# Erro ao testar app via SmartPhone

Tags: android

Quando tento testar minha aplicação via SmartPhone aparece esse erro.

```
12:34:20 Session 'app': Error Installing APK
```

Aparece essa mensagem no Debug

> com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device unauthorized.
>   This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set Try 'adb kill-server' if
>   that seems wrong. Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your
>   device. Error while Installing APK

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Teria como você detalhar melhor seu erro?

Comment: Parece-me ser alguma opção no smartphone, aparece lá alguma coisa?

Comment: Não aparece nada no celular, mas pode ser alguma configuração... estou procurando aqui.

Comment: Verifica se a depuração USB lá nas opções do desenvolvedor esta ativo, se tiver tenta revogar as autorizações de depuração usb, e conectar de novo, e permitir a depuração novamente

Comment: Tenta verificar se a depuração por USB está ativa!